# Open URL from the next cell on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets.

I have 2 buttons: **button start** (when clicked opens the first URL from B2 cell) and **button next** (when clicked should open B3 URL, then B4, then B5 and so on). The problem is on the Next function.

Can someone help me with this issue?

```
function start(){
  var i=2;
  open(i);
}

function open(i){
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B'+ i).getValue();
  var html = "<script>window.open('" + selection + "');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Opening page...');
}

function next(i){
  i++;
  open(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### When you call `function next(i)`, `i` is not defined.

If you want to store `i`'s value between two script calls, you need to use [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service.html). Hereby, [ScriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service.html#getScriptProperties()) allows you to save the value of a variable between two script calls.

**Sample:**

```
function start(){
  var i=2;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("i", i)
  open(i);
}

function open(i){
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B'+ i).getValue();
  var html = "<script>window.open('" + selection + "');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Opening page...');
}

function next(){
  var i=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("i")
  i++;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("i", i)
  open(i);
}
```